# What is this question actually asking for me to solve?

Tags: graphics, computer-graphics

(15 marks) Suppose a ray comes from a point (2, 8) and hits at mirror point (6, 6). Assume
that perpendicular vector a point (6, 6) is ̅= (0, 3). Find the reflection emitting point from
(6, 6).

[Assume 2-D coordinate system, you must draw the appropriate diagram of your
solution]

I'm pretty sure I can figure out the diagram, but I can't figure out what information I've been given and what is left for me to calculate. I can't draw a diagram that makes sense with what is being described. Does anyone know what I'm being asked here?

Comment: We require you to provide a reference to the source where you encountered this task: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: We are a question-and-answer site.  We require you to articulate a specific question in the body of your post.  Also, we are not looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  We are looking to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others.  And, we expect you to show us your progress and your thoughts.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @D.W., While I don't like the question much, it doesn't ask us to solve the exercise. While the post should specify what exactly is not clear in the statement, I myself don't know (and couldn't find) what "reflection emitting point" means, so the question "What is this question actually asking for me to solve?" sounds reasonable to me. Overall, I'm not sure the question should be closed.

Comment: @Dmitry yeah the issue is that this is a question for a Computer Graphics course at my school, but it's being poorly taught, and the question makes 0 sense. We were told to reference our notes for how to solve this, but the question is worded so poorly I have nothing to compare it to and was hoping someone on here would be able to decipher it. Thanks for trying

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to state explicitly what is unclear and ask a more specific question about the problem?  It would help if you focused on one specific aspect that you are unsure about or find unclear.

Comment: @D.W. how's that? I'm pretty lost with this question so I don't really know what I need to ask

Comment: @Kaleb why not ask the teacher for clarification?

Comment: @Juho because he is useless. I asked for clarification and he said:
"Focus on perpendicular which create 90 degree & point out the (0,3) point. Hopefully you understand.

With best regards."

Comment: I can't understand how to reconcile "I'm pretty sure I can figure out the diagram" and "I can't draw a diagram that makes sense with what is being described".

Comment: @D.W. It's pretty easy for me to draw a diagram for any of the three ways I can imagine interpreting the question, I was just unsure as to what interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the question is about a trick to handle reflections: rather than computing the direction of the incoming ray and deriving the direction of the outgoing ray, you can construct the symmetric of the emission point wrt the mirror. Then the reflected ray is the line from the reflected point through the hitting point.

[image]

Comment: Turns out the line through (0,3) and (6,6) was supposed to represent the mirror. Completely unclear from his wording though. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Kaleb: no, the mirror is not through (0,3).